# How to monitor which process modify a file in Windows?

Tags: windows, monitoring

For example, I want to monitor my hosts file. If some process changed my hosts file, I need to know which process and when that happens. How can I do that?

Comment: Programmatically or through a tool?

Comment: @KirkWoll Both ways are fine.

Comment: IIRC there's something built in NTFS for that.

Comment: Create a security audit on the file that triggers when somebody writes to it. Then look in the event log.

Comment: @RaymondChen How can I do that?

Comment: @HansPassant Is there some Windows API that I can use to monitor the file writing action? The I/O performance isn’t really a issue, I can turn off the monitor at anytime I want.

Comment: Look up "system access control list" in MSDN. Here's the page on [Audit Generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security audit will do the stuff.